# Firebase dynamiclink onSuccess nor onFailure getting called

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I am using the below code

```
        FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance()
                            .getDynamicLink(getIntent())
                            .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<PendingDynamicLinkData>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(PendingDynamicLinkData pendingDynamicLinkData) {
...
     }
                            })
                            .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                                }
                            });
```

I some devices, when I dont launch threw a deeplink, onSuccess is called with pendingDynamicLinkData == null, which is fine but on some devices, both onSuccess and onFailure not getting called at all. How to fix this?

Comment: Have you confirmed that the link handling code is getting called in those cases - e.g. if you put a breakpoint on the getDynamicLink line, it is being called?

Comment: the issue was with playservices not upgraded in those devices.. Later I noticed in the notification bar it asked to upgrade playservcise to use firebase

Comment: i also has the same issue, Please find a solution, not sure if only when launched through Android studio adb

Comment: I had a similar issue, 1st solution I found was with play service version check if in the logs are you getting error something like "Expected play service version XXXX but found version XXXX". It started working on some device but still I'm the issue persist for some devices particularly on "One+" devices. Please Answer if anyone has any more leads to solve this issue.

Comment: I suggest posting a different Stack Overflow question instead of tracking this old question. The issue may have something to do with how your app is set up or with the parameters configured on the Dynamic Link.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Omatt, you were somewhat correct, I finally figured it out and posted an answer too, in case anybody hits upon the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm getting you right you mean to say there are two cases happening inside your code with your firebase dynamic links:-

Case 1 -> On some devices the onSuccess(PendingDynamicLinkData pendingDynamicLinkData) method is being called. ( which is the expected behaviour)

Case 2 -> On some devices Neither the onSuccess(PendingDynamicLinkData pendingDynamicLinkData) callback is being called nor onFailure(Exception e).

I think this can if you are not executing your "Firebase.getInstance()..." part of the code in the activity which is currently in front of the user, or if the activity where you wrote this code is now in the background.

For Ex: If you execute this code( your Firebase.getInstance()... part of code) in your SplashActivity, which disappears usually after few seconds and your MainActivity is now present in front of the user, then in some devices Neither your OnSuccess(PendingDynamicLinkData pendingDynamicLinkData) nor your onFailure(Exception e) callback will be called.